# Running Apache JMeter from Command Prompt

Tags: cmd, jmeter

I have just started learning JMeter.

I am trying to run my script from command line ([cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)) in non GUI mode.

My [jmeter](/questions/tagged/jmeter) is placed in the `E:` drive.

Following is the path of `bin` directory for the same.

```
E:\Softwares\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin
```

I am running following command in `cmd.exe`:

```
E:\Softwares\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin>jmeter -n -t E:/Softwares/JMeter/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin/examples/jmeter for command line.jmx -l E:/Softwares/JMeter/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin/examples/new 1.csv
```

I am getting the following error:

```
An error occurred: Unknown arg: for

errorlevel=1
```

Comment: Quota paths that contain spaces: `jmeter -n -t "E:/Softwares/JMeter/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin/examples/jmeter for command line.jmx" -l "E:/Softwares/JMeter/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin/examples/new 1.csv"`

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

Escape the space as:

```
E:\Softwares\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin>jmeter -n -t E:/Softwares/JMeter/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin/examples/"jmeter for command line.jmx" -l E:/Softwares/JMeter/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin/examples/"new 1.csv"
```

## Explanation

`jmeter for command line.jmx` and `new 1.csv` are file names that contain spaces.

The space character is a separator for the system.

The separator is a special character (meta-character) that separates commands and arguments.

You can escape the space using quotes, such as by surrounding with double quotes `"`.

Another way to escape a meta-character on [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) is using the caret `^` by placing the caret right in front of it (rather than surrounding with double quotes).

### Example

```
E:\Softwares\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin>jmeter -n -t E:/Softwares/JMeter/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin/examples/jmeter^ for^ command line.jmx -l E:/Softwares/JMeter/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin/examples/new^ 1.csv
```

### Extra

Note that space is not the only meta character, other meta characters such as `>` (output redirection - [stdout](/questions/tagged/stdout)) also can be escaped in the same way, such as when setting the prompt: `prompt ^>`.

Also, you don't have to specify the full file path for `-t` and `-l` [switches](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) of [jmeter](/questions/tagged/jmeter), you can reference files using relative path instead, which is shorter.

Consider:

```
E:\Softwares\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin>jmeter -n -t examples/"jmeter for command line.jmx" -l examples/"new 1.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

JMeter provides command line support to execute the test. Command is given below

```
jmeter -n –t <Your-JMX-file.jmx> -l <test-results.jtl>
```

More details available here - https://www.testodev.com/2018/06/jmeter-in-non-gui-mode.html